# EPSON TMT88IV Printer using IP Address

Tags: java, printers, network-printers, epson, javapos

I have a EPSON TMT88IV receipt printer.I have connected it my office network.We have an external IP address.Is possible to print anything from out side of my network over the IP address.

I am interested to using their Java POS.Anybody know how i print using IP address.

Help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
VKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The safest way is to establish a VPN to your office network with full security.

When that is done, you should be able to print directly to it the same way you would do directly from the network.

Comment: thank you for ur reply,if i print directly using IP address, i need a printer driver in my machine?

Comment: If the printer requires a special driver, you most likely need to.